# Render Partial View in Correct Location

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, asp.net-mvc-partialview

**Trying to:**
Place a partial view within a telerik tabstrip.

**Problem:**
The view is being displayed above the tab strip instead of within the first tab.

**What I have tried:**
If I use RenderPage instead of RenderAction then the view correctly appears inside the tabstrip however then the controller does not get called or load the model for the gridview.

**Code so far:**

*Partial View:*

```
@model IEnumerable<MyModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@*My code to load a GridView*@
```

*View containing tab strip:*

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyView";
}


@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
          .Name("tabstrip")
          .Items(tabstrip =>
          {
              tabstrip.Add().Text("Index")
                  .Selected(true)
                  .Content(@<text>
                    @{Html.RenderAction("Index", "MyController");}
                </text>);
              tabstrip.Add().Text("Index2")
                  .Content(@<text>
                </text>);                                 
          })
)
```

Comment: What happens if you use `.Content(@<text>@Html.Action("Index", "MyController")</text>);` ?

Comment: @Lanorkin that places the table in the correct location but unfortunately it also duplicates the footer from the main _layout page as well.

Comment: @Lanorkin my bad - I wasn't using partialview.  Please post your comment as a solution.

Comment: Actually I don't see myself how that differs from the way you use it, so I was just some sort of thinking aloud. The way you use it should just work if it was issue with partial view.

Comment: @Lanorkin I don't understand either but it wasn't to do with partial view.  I just changed it back to renderaction and it moves back above the tabstrip.

Comment: There should be an overload which accepts an URL. Set the URL of the action which returns your partial view and please, please, please remove the `<text>` tag from there. Actually, you can [load the content trough AJAX](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/tabstrip/ajax) and instead of `Url.Content` use `Url.Action`.

Comment: @Andrei V Removing the text tag cause the code to fail with `An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately`

Comment: Please see the example at the link above. Use `LoadContentFrom` instead of `Content`.

Comment: @Andrei V I tried your suggestion but it displays nothing/blank.  `tabstrip.Add().Text("Index") .LoadContentFrom(Url.Action("~/Views/Index.cshtml")             
                );`

Comment: `LoadContentFrom` expects a URL which is called using AJAX. This URL needs to reach an Action inside one of your controllers: `tabstrip.Add().Text("Index").Selected(true)                   .LoadContentFrom(Html.Action("Index", "MyController"))`.

Comment: @Andrei V works perfectly thanks.  Can you post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Content` configuration method of a Kendo UI TabStrip should be used for "static" content. By static I mean code that you already have/know. For loading partial views it is best to use the `LoadContentFrom` configuration method. This method requires a valid URL of an existing Action, which returns the targeted partial view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
      .Name("tabstrip")
      .Items(tabstrip =>
      {
          tabstrip.Add().Text("Index")
              .Selected(true)
              .LoadContentFrom(Html.Action("Index", "MyController"));
          tabstrip.Add().Text("Index2")
              .Content(@<text>
            </text>);                                 
      })
```

)