# How to Render a Partial View within a Telerik TabStrip control?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

Beyond confused with Telerik's documentation here.

I have a `TabStrip` Control, taken and slightly adapted from Telerik's example:

```
<button id="actuallyClose" class="removeItem k-button" style="visibility:hidden">X</button>
<div id="tabstrip">
    <ul>
        <li id="open" class="k-button">Add +</li>
    </ul>

    <div>
        Please Complete The following:
        <br />
        Tab name: <input id="newTabName" type="text" />
        <button class="appendItem k-button">Append</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

With the **Javascript** being:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var getItem = function (target) {
                var itemIndex = target[0].value;

                return tabStrip.tabGroup.children("li").eq(itemIndex);
            },
            select = function (e) {
                if (e.type != "keypress" || kendo.keys.ENTER == e.keyCode)
                    tabStrip.select(getItem($("#tabIndex")));
            },
            append = function (e) {
                if (e.type != "keypress" || kendo.keys.ENTER == e.keyCode)
                    tabStrip.append({
                        encoded:false,
                        text: $("#newTabName").val() + '<button onclick="; actuallyClose.click();">X</button>',
                        encoded:false,
                        content: "<div><br/></div>", /*would like to render a view here!!!*/
                        spriteCssClass: "tabCloseBtn",
                    }

                    );
            },

          ...

            $(".removeItem").click(function (e) {
                var tab = tabStrip.select(),
                otherTab = tab.next();
                otherTab = otherTab.length ? otherTab : tab.prev();

                tabStrip.remove(tab);
                tabStrip.select(otherTab);
            });

         ...

            $(".appendItem").click(append);
            $("#appendText").keypress(append);

          ...
        });

        var tabStrip = $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip().data("kendoTabStrip");



        $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
            animation: {
                // fade-out current tab over 1000 milliseconds
                close: {
                    duration: 1000,
                    effects: "fadeOut"
                },
                // fade-in new tab over 500 milliseconds
                open: {
                    duration: 500,
                    height: "100%",
                    width: "96%",
                    effects: "fadeIn"
                }
            }
        });

    </script>
```

I am ***completely*** confused about how to add/render a partial view within this 'added' tab.

I wish to render the View '(Index, Home)' for example.

However, I can't seem to find the answer ANYWHERE :(

The closest I've found was:

```
LoadContentFrom(@Html.Action("Index", "MyController")),
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946346/render-partial-view-in-correct-location) - but I still get the OP's problem.

I think i need to declare something in this script:

```
         append = function (e) {
                if (e.type != "keypress" || kendo.keys.ENTER == e.keyCode)
                    tabStrip.append({
                        encoded:false,
                        text: $("#newTabName").val() + '<button onclick="; actuallyClose.click();">X</button>',
                        encoded:false,
                        content: "<div><br/></div>", /*would like to render a view here!!!*/
                        spriteCssClass: "tabCloseBtn",
                    }
                    );
            },
```

My current design is:

[image: this]

I would like to have a default 'index' view appear under the 'New Tab Name' tab (once append button is pressed)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Let me see if I get your right: You want to add a new tab dynamically when "Append" is pressed under the name of the text input value. This new tab must have the contents of a partial view(always the same?). Right?

Comment: yes. I want the 'Index' to appear as default (for now, anyway)

Comment: Well, you can load a view async using `contentURl` parameter, but a request will open the get the view everytime, but its quite simple. Check [this](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip#methods-append) out.

Comment: I've already seen that. Doesn't seem to work too well. (1) Cause i'm using Local host to test, it doesn't like that and (2) it doesn't seem tp support tilde's inorder to show a relative path :L

Comment: What you can do is to create the tab and in the content you set just a div. Then in that div you use jquery's [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function to get your partial. We have some code working like that.

Comment: That could be a workable hack, I suppose (you can probably tell that's similar to how i got the internal 'close tab' button working)

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown could you possibly supply a snippet? this is doing my head in right now (telerik really doesn't seem to want to be helpful)!

Comment: I thought you don't want the solution I have porposed.

Comment: I said it could be a hack, but since i'm already using one I don't think it really matters :P

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery's [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to render your partial:

```
var tabCounter = 1; // A global variable or anything like it

append = function (e) {
    if (e.type != "keypress" || kendo.keys.ENTER == e.keyCode)
    {
        tabStrip.append({
            encoded:false,
            text: $("#newTabName").val() + '<button onclick="; actuallyClose.click();">X</button>',
            encoded:false,
            content: "<div id='tab" + tabCounter + "'></div>", 
            spriteCssClass: "tabCloseBtn",
        });

        $("#tab" + tabCounter).load("url/goes/here", function()
        {
            // Load Complete
            tabCounter++;
        }
    }
},
```

Negative points:

1. It is not the ideal solution but I already had problems with that `content` properties to load asyn content too. But I'm afraid that kendo may use the jQuery load() function behind the scenes since it uses jQuery's ajax api as well;
2. The view content will be load everytime. I don't know if the content can be load only once and then, reused, must search for it;
3. If the view load take much time than expected, user can try to see the tab and face a blank content. A loading image could be helpful.